# Запрос на выбор уникальных записей с таблицы MySQL по дате

Tags: запрос, mysql

```
id2___________________text____________________________data

1187__________________111_____________________________2013-06-22

1187__________________111_____________________________2013-06-18

1188__________________22222222________________________2013-06-23

1188__________________22222222________________________2013-06-20

1189__________________3333333_________________________2013-06-23

1189__________________3333333_________________________2013-06-20
```

Есть таблица (выше). 
Необходимо выбрать записи по полю "data" с 2013-06-17 по 2013-06-24,
чтобы в результате выводились уникальные записи по полю "id2", **и что бы они были с более ранней датой**.
Должно получится такой результат:

```
id2___________________text______________________data

1187__________________111_______________________2013-06-18

1188__________________22222222__________________2013-06-20

1189__________________3333333___________________2013-06-20
```

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо! Вот как я сам додул вчера)) Спасибо Вам Юрий

```
SELECT id2, text, data

FROM   tab s1

WHERE  data >= '2013-06-17' and data <=  '2013-06-24' and data=(SELECT MIN(s2.data )

FROM tab  s2

WHERE s1.id2 = s2.id2)

GROUP BY id2
```

Answer (score 3):

Довольно простой запрос, почему он вызывает затруднения? Документацию читали?

```
select `id2`, `text`, min(`data`)
from `tab`
where 
  `data` between '2013-06-17 00:00:00' and '2013-06-24 00:00:00'
group by `id2`, `text`
```